# Conversion from PointCloud to Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

Let's say I initialize a point-cloud. I want to store its RGB channels in opencv's Mat data-type. How can I do that?

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);   //Create a new cloud
pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> ("cloud.pcd", *cloud);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand it right, that you are only interested in the RGB-values of the point-cloud and don't care about its XYZ-values?

Then you can do:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>); 
//Create a new cloud
pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> ("cloud.pcd", *cloud);

cv::Mat result; 

if (cloud->isOrganized()) {
    result = cv::Mat(cloud->height, cloud->width, CV_8UC3);

    if (!cloud->empty()) {

        for (int h=0; h<result.rows; h++) {
            for (int w=0; w<result.cols; w++) {
                pcl::PointXYZRGBA point = cloud->at(w, h);

                Eigen::Vector3i rgb = point.getRGBVector3i();

                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(h,w)[0] = rgb[2];
                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(h,w)[1] = rgb[1];
                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(h,w)[2] = rgb[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's enough to show the basic idea.

BUT this only works, if your point-cloud is organized:

> An **organized point cloud** dataset is the name given to point clouds
>   that resemble an organized image (or matrix) like structure, where the
>   data is split into rows and columns. Examples of such point clouds
>   include data coming from stereo cameras or Time Of Flight cameras. The
>   advantages of a organized dataset is that by knowing the relationship
>   between adjacent points (e.g. pixels), nearest neighbor operations are
>   much more efficient, thus speeding up the computation and lowering the
>   costs of certain algorithms in PCL. [(Source)](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php)

Comment: Also, if you build the example code, you can actually use `pcl2png [/path/to.pcd] [/path/to.png]` [see here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/tools/pcd2png.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

I know how to convert from Mat(3D Image) to XYZRGB. I think you can figure out the other way. Here Q is disparity to depth Matrix.

```
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
 double px, py, pz;
 uchar pr, pg, pb;

 for (int i = 0; i < img_rgb.rows; i++)
 {
     uchar* rgb_ptr = img_rgb.ptr<uchar>(i);
     uchar* disp_ptr = img_disparity.ptr<uchar>(i);
     double* recons_ptr = recons3D.ptr<double>(i);
     for (int j = 0; j < img_rgb.cols; j++)
     {
         //Get 3D coordinates

          uchar d = disp_ptr[j];
          if ( d == 0 ) continue; //Discard bad pixels
          double pw = -1.0 * static_cast<double>(d) * Q32 + Q33; 
          px = static_cast<double>(j) + Q03;
          py = static_cast<double>(i) + Q13;
          pz = Q23;

          // Normalize the points
          px = px/pw;
          py = py/pw;
          pz = pz/pw;

          //Get RGB info
          pb = rgb_ptr[3*j];
          pg = rgb_ptr[3*j+1];
          pr = rgb_ptr[3*j+2];

          //Insert info into point cloud structure
          pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
          point.x = px;
          point.y = py;
          point.z = pz;
          uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(pr) << 16 |
          static_cast<uint32_t>(pg) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(pb));
          point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
          point_cloud_ptr->points.push_back (point);
    }
}

point_cloud_ptr->width = (int) point_cloud_ptr->points.size();
point_cloud_ptr->height = 1;
```

Comment: This is definitely not an answer for this question! Besides, few of the variables are not defined so it adds the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I succeed to solve it!

You should firstly transform the coordinate so that your 'ground plane' is the X-O-Y plane.
The core api is [pcl::getTransformationFromTwoUnitVectorsAndOrigin](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.2/a02405.html#ga4375e99ec2ae368eec9379f506568611)

You can have a look at my [question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827325/how-to-project-point-cloud-onto-the-ground-plane-and-transfer-it-into-an-2d-imag)

good luck!